# Use Javascript to select a colour declared in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to create a donut chart. The colours for each section are defined in the options passed via JS.

```
   self.chartView = new Donut({
      el: this,
      colors: ['#96c6e3','#d8c395','#7fb299','#c693c3'],
      data: $(this).data('series')
    });
```

I would like to define these colours in CSS and then grab them for donut chart. Something along the lines of:

**CSS**

```
#color1{
    background-color: #96c6e3;
}
```

**JS**

```
    self.chartView = new Donut({
      el: this,
      colors: [$('#color1').css('background-color') ],
      data: $(this).data('series')
    });
```

But I'm not even sure this is possible.

Comment: What is wrong with `colors: ['#96c6e3','#d8c395','#7fb299','#c693c3']`?

Comment: `colors: [$('#color1').css('background-color') ]` this will work as soon as you are sure that there will be a element with `id=color1` in your DOM

Comment: The data is being pulled from a database and I would like the colours to be consistent across this graph and multiple other tables and graphs. The parameters may change in the future and I want to basically match the colour with the ID returned from the database. If I can declare a set ID colour in the CSS then I can make it consistent across the board.

Comment: @laaposto So the CSS will be loaded before the JS so long as an element with that ID exists? Well that would work fine...

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdrrvx3f/

Comment: Great, if you set this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, see this code snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  var colors = [
    $('#color1').css('background-color'),
    $('#color2').css('background-color')
  ];

  $('#container').highcharts({
    colors: colors,
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Browser share',
      data: [
        ['Firefox', 45.0],
        ['IE', 26.8]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
#color1 {
  background-color: #96c6e3;
}

#color2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#colors {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="colors">
  <div id="color1"></div>
  <div id="color2"></div>
</div>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```